# How can I use VB.Net to read the content returned from a URL?

Tags: vb.net, http, redirect

Below is the example code I'm using to get this to work and it does work if I try to read yahoo.com.

Here is the problem. The address I need to read is a java servlet that processes parameters passed in, generates a text document on the server, and then redirects to another URL and returns the address of the text file on the server.  I then need to download that text file and process it. I'm having problems connecting to the first URL with the parameters and I think it has to do with the redirect.

I'm using the WebRequest object and I've tried using the HttpWebRequest object. Are there any other objects that support redirects?

TIA

```
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim request As WebRequest
    Dim response As WebResponse
    Dim data As String = ""

    Try
        request = WebRequest.Create("URL Here")
        request.Timeout = 30000
        response = request.GetResponse()
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        data = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return data
```

Comment: What does the String you are using look like?  What is the error message look like... Update you question with this info.

Comment: So you redirect 2xtimes before getting the final url of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something that will work.

I used a WebBrowser control instead.

Have a button that runs this code...

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("URL Here")
```

And this function to process once the request returns.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated    
    MsgBox(WebBrowser1.DocumentText)    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

I just tested out HttpWebRequest.Create() and that does  handle the 301 and 302 fine with out extra code.

Can you post the error you are seeing

---

You could cast the WebResponse to a HttpWebResponse:

I need to convert this to VB... but it might help you start:

```
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
{
    // Follow Redirect,  new request based off Redirect
}

// Read Data
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with the request object because I get a 500 Internal Server error when using the correct address. I tried your suggestion, but I still get the error.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a 500 from your server of a 500 from the response server?

Comment: The address is to a customer's server. The error occurs on the GetResponse() line so it must be coming from their server. But, like I said, if I replace the URL with www.yahoo.com, it works fine. So confused...

Comment: See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

Comment: ************** Exception Text **************
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HOPRequirements.Form1.GetDataURL() in c:\my documents\My Projects\Repositories\HOPRequirements\HOPRequirements\Form1.vb:line 64
   at HOPRequirements.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\my documents\My Projects\Repositories\HOPRequirements\HOPRequirements\Form1.vb:line 22
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: Do you know what a 500 error is?  http://status-code.com/, What ever you are requesting from the server is causing an error on the server... there is no redirect issues...

Comment: Yeah, I know the error.  The weird thing is that when I take the same exact string and copy/paste it into the browser (IE), it works fine.

Comment: If you control said server, You should check the error logs on that server... else you are in a hard place. you need to get some info  from that server, to see why its throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just have to set the [AutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28VS.80%29.aspx) property.

```
request.AutoRedirect = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    webRequest = webRequest.Create(URL)
    webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
    inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
```

[Read URL full source code](http://vb.net-informations.com/communications/vb.net_read_url.htm)

winston