# vb.net - how to get real link from php url

Tags: c#, php, vb.net

I have an example URL (`http://www.techspot.com/downloads.php?action=download_now&id=2991&evp=113a02f49ca8ac11b566336b984b1655&file=1`). And when I click the link, the url will change to:

```
http://www.exisoftware.com/downloads/picture_finder/PictureFinderSetup.exe
```

Can anyone help me how to convert the php link to real url using vb.net or c#?

Because when I make a program to check file information in vb.net using HEAD method the file name not "`PictureFinderSetup.exe`" but "`downloads.php`?`action=download_now&id=2991&evp=113a02f49ca8ac11b566336b984b1655&file=1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done without contacting the server. Only the server knows the exact mapping.
From Fiddler:
Request

```
GET http://www.techspot.com/downloads.php?action=download_now&id=2991&evp=113a02f49ca8ac11b566336b984b1655&file=1 HTTP/1.1
...
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 17:26:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.techspot.com/downloads/2991-extreme-picture-finder.html
```

To get the information you can use `WebBrowser` or HttpWebResponse to get data you need. [How can I use VB.Net to read the content returned from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293789/how-can-i-use-vb-net-to-read-the-content-returned-from-a-url)